# Cursor hangs for a second when turning off sound system from the powerstrip

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a curios hardware issue that I'm worried about.
I have my desktop plugged into a regular power strip without surge protection or on/off switches. In one of its plugs there's another **power strip** - this one has **on/off buttons** for each individual plug.

In one of the 3 plugs I've plugged in my **sound system**. I want the convenience of a power on/off switch on the plug because it draws power even when turned off, and buzzes faintly (my head is next to it when I sleep so it matters).

But when I hit the button to turn off the sound system at the plug, the mouse freezes for a second on the screen!

Is this normal? I have had some power issues in the past (fried PSU repeatedly, USB mice damaged - and strangely enough even when I had a UPS) and I want to understand what could be going on.

EDIT: I'm using an HP X1500 **USB mouse**. The plugs in my house are European dual round-pronged, but they **lack the grounding clips** that [Schuko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#mediaviewer/File:Schuko_plug_and_socket.png) plugs have. So maybe that's it. I have had decent PSUs... now I use one by Corsair.

Comment: What kind of mouse are you using?

Comment: Grounding: Has the 3rd pin of the electrical connection been defeated in any way? (adapter, pin removed, etc?)  Is it being plugged into a good 3 prong outlet?   You mention plug strip is plugged into plug strip, are you sure you're not creating the problem with an overload? Are you buying cheap PSU's as you repeatedly replace them?